# <coroutine object Messageable.send at 0x00000228114ADE00> error

Tags: python

I'm just code a bot its ask before kick and ban and its have an error:

<coroutine object Messageable.send at 0x00000228114ADE00>

The message to kick is:

!bot/kick @user

Code(the part make it error):

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True, administrator = True)
async def kick(ctx,self, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    message = ctx.send(f"Are you sure to kick {member.mention}(Timeout 20 seconds)")
    await ctx.send(message)
    await message.add_reaction(":thumbsup:")
    await message.add_reaction(":thumbsdown:")
    check = lambda r, u: u == ctx.author and str(r.emoji) in ":thumbsup::thumbsdown:"
    
    
    try:
        reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check, timeout=20)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.edit(content="Kick cancelled, timed out.")
        return

    if str(reaction.emoji) == ":thumbsup:":
        await member.ban()
        await message.edit(content=f"{member.mention} has been kicked.")
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
        return
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == ":thumbsdown:":
        await message.edit(content=f"Kick has been cancelled")
        return
    await message.edit(content="Kick cancelled.")
```

Comment: `ctx.send` is a coroutine. It must be awaited. So instead of a `Message` object, `message` becomes a coroutine object

Comment: `coroutine` can't run them selfs. They need an eventloop to run..